# Renaming multiple folders with number sequence

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, rename

This is my folders list. They are not in sequence (they dont start from #1). I want to rename these folder sequence 1-348 (there are 348 folders). How can i do that?
I have folders list like this. [sample img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytnah.png)
I want to make it like this.
[sample img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Y6l.png)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to list all sub-directories in the current directory, sort them in ascending order (assuming all their names are integers), and then re-map them to new names using consecutive numbers.

```py
import os
import os.path

dirs_unsorted = filter(lambda d: os.path.isdir(d), map(lambda d: d.name, os.scandir(".")))
dirs = sorted(dirs_unsorted, reverse=False, key=int)

for t in enumerate(dirs):
    i,name = t
    new_name = str(i+1)
    print("Renaming {0} to {1}".format(name, new_name))
    os.rename(name,new_name)
```